# Find Value in Last Instance of Multiple Record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I'm new to Access and SQL so I'm having a bit of trouble with this undoubtedly simple issue.

I'm using VBA and SQL to update a table based on a few `listbox` selections.

One of the fields I'm updating is an "instance" field which tracks the instance number of each ID. For example, the first time ID 5 was added to the table its instance number would be 1. The second time it was added to the table its instance would be 2. So it would look like this:

```
ID        |      Date       |     InstanceNUM    |
005       |    11/22/2013   |         1          |
005       |    11/23/2013   |         2          |
```

and so on. It's likely that other records would/will separate the two records in the example above.

After doing some research, it seems like `DLast` is the best function for this job since the last instance of the particular ID will also contain the instance number in field three. However, when I use this syntax:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim IDnum As Long
i = DLast("[InstanceNum]", "tbl_Data", [ID] = IDnum)
'where [InstanceNum] is the field name for the value I want to return, _
'"tbl_Data" is the table name where the value I want to return exists, _
'and [ID] is the field name where the ID exists.
```

I get the `Run-time error '94': Invalid use of Null`. My understanding of this error is that `DLast` couldn't find a value based on this criteria (and it can't store that result in a `Long` data type variable), but I know that the record exists (I've checked the table for the value and I've checked the variable for the value). 
**EDIT**
The [ID] field is a text data type. I set the IDnum variable this way:

```
Dim IDnum As String
Set ctlList = Me!List7  

For i = 0 To ctlList.ListCount - 1
    If ctlList.Selected(i) = True Then
        IDnum = ctlList.Column(0, i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next I
```

The above code loops through a listbox in a form I have and sets the IDnum variable as the ID number in the first column.

Per HansUp's suggestion, I have updated my code to this:

```
i = DLast("InstanceNum", "tbl_Data", "[ID] =" & IDnum)
```

But now I get the `Run-time error '3464': Data type mismatch in criteria expression.`

I'm at a loss for why this is happening. Perhaps there's an easy answer to this, but I haven't been able to find one... And maybe there's an easier way to do this? Does anyone know why this error is happening?

Comment: I get the same error when I change the data type of IDnum to `String` and convert the ID number to a string... am I going about this the wrong way? Perhaps I've misunderstood what `DLast()` is used for?

Comment: @HansUp Please see my edits. Like I mention in my post, I've checked the value of `IDnum` during run time and it matches the ID I'm looking for in the proper table. I've even gone so far as to set the value of `IDnum` using the immediate window to be sure I have the proper value set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `[ID]` is text type, add quotes around the value of `IDnum` for `DLast`.

```vb
i = DLast("InstanceNum", "tbl_Data", "[ID] = '" & IDnum & "'")
```

However if the stored `[ID]` values include leading zeros, you must `Format` `IDnum` to include those.

```vb
i = DLast("InstanceNum", "tbl_Data", "[ID] = '" & Format(IDnum, "000") & "'")
```

Comment: +1 Ah! Perfect! Thank you so much for your time! I've been at this for hours!

Comment: There will be multiple users... although I think it's unlikely that an update like that would happen. If I find that happening, is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Yes.  Since you're using Access 2010, you might benefit from a data macro.  However, I haven't yet explored those myself so can't say more.  Look into it and see whether it's worth a new question.